# Make setup exe in VS 2010 that runs only one computer

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i create a project in VS2010 and database in SQL-SERVER 2008 . i want to make a setup for the app

i want to make it like it install on a computer with a serial key. and after installation , it cant be install on other computer without my permission.

i mean i want to protect my app . i want that it takes the computer ip address or anything else some id type thing. and if it not same then it will bi not install or run

plz help me i want to do it but don't know how ?
in VS2010 .help plz

i want that one cd or setup run only one computer . for other comp the user must call me and buy a cd or setup .

plzzzz help , thanks !

Comment: This has nothing to do with VS2010. Consider using licencing products such as http://soraco.co/QuickLicenseManager.aspx

Comment: it is too costly for me and also it has more functionality, i need this only for vb.net application So would you please suggest me any other alternative.....thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

Friend,

Visual Studio will not provide an option which you looking for.

Better have your application design like, give an option like opening a application using password or serial key sort of.

Don't disclose the key to anyone. when any attempted and failed to login, give a message to contact you with your contact details.

Hope this helpful to you,

Regards,

Deepak